# svn update <directory> -r HEAD --force Still leaves dirty copies of local files

Tags: eclipse, svn

I want to update to the latest revision of selenium code(http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk) daily.

I just select the folder in my eclipse,right click,team and select update to HEAD.Buty , this leaves dirty copy of some directories and files..

What i am looking for is: **I always want to checkout the latest code from repository to the local directory overwriting local changes,if any**

NOTE: I don't have commit rights, I just want the latest code from repository overriding my local changes.

Comment: Just curious, what and why do you change in selenium sources?

Comment: I want to become a committer of the selenium project.I know it sounds funny :) (With the kind of questions, i am asking).

Comment: it is praiseworthy, actually. Opensource projects is a good way to improve skills, doesn't matter how skilled you are now.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You need to do a `svn revert -R <directory>` first.

`svn update --force` forces the update to overwrite *unversioned* files, not local changes to versioned files.

Comment: @javanoob: If you're happy to lose all local changes to versioned files, then yes.

Comment: I wish I could upvote this a million times. This really helped me out.

Answer (score 1):

Use this line:

```
svn revert -R .;svn up
```